# Changes to Main Menu are not saved

Tags: menu, alacarte

I am unable to find a way to edit the Main Menu on my system (see attached image of my menu).  I have tried using "alacarte", "mozo" and "menulibre". When I make changes to the menu in (for example) mozo, the change shows up in the mozo app but then when I go to the menu itself, the change does not show up even if I logout and login or if I reboot. In other words, my changes are not properly saved to my system, using any of these three apps.  My system information:
$ wmctrl -m
Name: Metacity (Marco)

$ printf 'Desktop: %s\nSession: %s\n' "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" "$GDMSESSION"
Desktop: MATE
Session: mate

$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

Does anyone know what's going on and how to fix it?

Patrick

[Image of the "menu" I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqzLv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved this problem as follows:
Using the "Mate Tweak" application ([from the universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)), in the "Panel" tab I changed the "Panel" from "Familiar" to "Traditional".  Then I removed the "alacarte" and "menulibre" menu editors ...leaving only "mozo" which is apparently the correct Menu editor to use for Mate.   I noticed that when deleting an application, it stays on the menu until I log out and log back in - but other changes show up instantly in the menu without logging-out.
The "Traditional" menu looks slightly different; it has three Top-level options: "Applications, Places, System" but I'm totally okay with that - in fact I prefer it.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Great work answering your own question!